# Cannot pass flags to Makefile to compile my code

Tags: makefile, gdal

I have a project that basically compiles from the command line in the following form:
`g++ -o stack_raster stack_raster.cpp -lgdal -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system`

I made a Makefile, and this is the content:

```
CXX =g++ 
LDDFLAGS = -lgdal -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
all: clean stack_raster 
clean: 
    rm -f stack_raster
```

However I got a collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status. 
A second variation of my Makefile I tried was:

```
CXX = g++ 
CPPFLAGS = -lgdal -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem 
all: clean stack_raster 
clean:
    rem -f stack_raster
```

but I still receive the following message (even though the compile flags appear as they should for my program to compile successfully).

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target `stack_raster` failed 
make: *** [stack_raster] Error 1
```

Does anyone could help me with a reference or hint about my problem, and how could I tackle it?

Comment: Does your makefile really define variable `LDDFLAGS`, as opposed to `LDFLAGS`?  The former has no standard significance I know of (but changing to the latter is probably not the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone could help me with a reference or hint about my problem, and how could I tackle it?

To begin with, you should have a look at the actual link command that `make` executed.  It should have been echoed to `make`'s output just before the error message from `collect2`.  Understanding what's wrong with the command is the first step in determining how to fix your makefile.

In the first case, the command is probably something like

```
g++ stack_raster.cpp -o stack_raster
```

In the second, it is probably something like

```
g++ -lgdal -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem stack_raster.cpp -o stack_raster
```

The latter is probably also very similar to what you would get with the first makefile if you corrected the spelling of `LDDFLAGS` to `LDFLAGS`.

You will note that the library flags come in a different place in that command than they do in your manual command, and I assume you know that the order of objects and library flags on the linker command line is significant to Unix-style linkers such as GNU's (which is the one that the `g++` driver will use).

You can certainly fix this by writing an explicit rule, as you describe in your own answer, but your `make`s' built-in rules may be up to the task, too.  If you are using GNU `make` then they certainly are.  For this purpose it is useful to know what the built-in rules actually are, and essential to know what the variables on which these rules depend mean.

Specifically,

- `LDFLAGS` provides options to pass when invoking the linker, and *conventionally, they appear on the command line **before** the objects being linked*.  As a result, this variable typically is not appropriate for specifying libraries (but it is fine for other link-specific options, such as `-L` to add directories to the library search path).
- `CPPFLAGS` provides options for modulating the behavior of the C preprocessor (including when compiling C++).  These do not typically appear at all in link(-only) commands executed by `make`, but they will appear (early) in commands for compiling object files from C or C++ sources, and in rules for building executables directly from C or C++ sources.

Neither of those is what you want, but if you are using GNU make, then [its documentation for the former](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#index-LDFLAGS) explicitly tells you what (with that `make` implementation) you should do instead:

> Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the
>   linker, ‘`ld`’, such as `-L`. **Libraries (`-lfoo`) should be added to the
>   `LDLIBS` variable instead.**

(emphasis added)

In GNU `make`, and perhaps some others, the `LDLIBS` variable serves exactly the purpose you need: to specify the libraries to link.  These will appear at the end of the link command line from built-in rules, as you can confirm from GNU `make`'s [catalog of implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), or from the list obtainable by running `make -p` in a directory containing no makefile.

So, with GNU `make` you can get the build you seem to want from the built-in rules, with this:

```
CXX = g++ 
LDLIBS = -lgdal -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem

all: clean stack_raster 

clean: 
    rm -f stack_raster
```

In closing, I note that cleaning before building by default, as your examples do and mine imitates, largely defeats the purpose of using `make` instead of a simple script.  Part of the point of `make` is to do the minimum work necessary, and if your target executable is present and not out of date with respect to its sources then there is no reason to force it to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer:
[Set up my makefile to compile C with just "make"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119488/set-up-my-makefile-to-compile-c-with-just-make)

YOu have to specify in the Makefile the file you want to create in this case stack_raster.exe and the *objective*  file in this case stack_raster.cpp and specify the command line arguments you normally pass for compiling. So the Makefile would be something like:

```
CXX=g++
stack_raster.exe: stack_raster.cpp
    g++ -o stack_raster.exe stack_raster.cpp -lgdal -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system 
all: clean stack_raster.exe 
clean: 
    rm -f stack_raster.exe
```

Comment: Why introduce a `.exe` extension that is not present in the question?  I realize that this is a self-answer, but it feels like it is answering a different question than was actually posed.

Comment: Sorry that was my fault. I was playing around, looking some examples on the internet, and in one of them they put the .exe extension, that turns out to be very irrelevant. Thanks for your help! You answer definitely clarifies my doubts regarding this topic